# Excel 2007 automatically starts debugger when showing dialog

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm and when I display it `dlg.Show vbModal` excel is entering the debugger. There's no error, it just enters the debugger - like it thinks it has hung. How do I stop it from enter the debugger?

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit? Does it stop at that line after opening the VBA Editor or it just opens the VBA Editor and continues the rest of the code?

Comment: It breaks on dlg.Show. It waits for me to press F5 to continue. It breaks as soon as the dialog is shown.

Comment: This apparently is an undocumented bug (I have seen this problem mentioned in forums before) and unfortunately could never see a solution to this. The same code if you will try in any other pc will work fine. :)

Comment: I rebooted the computer and now it works fine.

Comment: Just did a quick google search and immediately got this link. http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=143709. Seems like this user is facing same problem as yours?

Comment: `I rebooted the computer and now it works fine`Ah! The old trick LOL

Comment: Found one more link which might be related to your scenario. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/843697. Next time it occurs do not restart but do as suggested in this link and see if it helps?

Answer (score 1):

Moving my comment to an answer so that this question doesn't get [DELETED](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) automatically.

**Reason Why this happens**:

For some reason, the VBA project thinks a breakpoint existed within that event script, so the VBA editor stops on that particular line of code, although there is no visible breakpoint seen.

**Two ways to solve this problem**:

1. As per [THIS MSDN ARTICLE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/843697), select the `Clear All Breakpoints` option under the Debug menu.

[image]

2. If the above doesn't work, then simply re-start your pc. Remember to save your work if applicable.